# Semaphores and Threadpools in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I am not very clear on concept of semaphores in Java and trying to understand it.

My understanding after reading oracle docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and some other pages, its similar to a lock with a count of number of permits.

It is usually used to create pools of resources. 
Here I get confused, there is also ThreadPoolExecutor which can give me a pool of threads. So what is the difference? Which one is used in what scenario?

Answer (score 12):

First of all, there is no such thing as a stupid question...

[Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) allows multiple threads to "acquire" a resource. They should check if the resource is available. It's like a valve for flow control.

A [Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) is for exclusive access. Only one thread at a time.

A [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) allows you to run some code (Runnable or Callable class) using a bounded amount of threads. You don't have to bother about building this yourself, it is already implemented for you in the JSE API. You could do your own with some semaphores and queues... but if you do not have a good reason do not waste your time.

Imagine you have to implement a web server that receives some requests to port 80. You do not want to use the same thread that is listening to this port to process the whole request (this is a waste of resources...). You could use a ThreadPoolExecutor deal with the request, process it, and respond to the client.  ThreadPoolExecutor could be configured to take advantage of the current CPUs: the optimal number of threads for this architecture and this task.

[Concurrency in practice](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/) is a nice book to improve your knowledge on this matter.

I hope this help you and sorry for my basic English.

Answer (score 1):

A ThreadPool is a pool of one of more threads which can be managed collectively.  In Java The ThreadPoolExecutor also has a queue while you give it Runnable or Callable to execute and it can return a Future which allows you to control the task or obtain a result.

A Semaphore just allows you to obtain a number of permits e.g. it can allow two threads at most to run some code.  You need a number of threads running to give it a purpose, but otherwise they are unrelated.

BTW: I would read the documentation for Java 7 as Java 5.0 has been EOL for some time and Java 6 is almost at an End of Free Service.

Comment: Thanks for pointing for java 7 docs. I just googled and open the link.

Comment: google is a little out of date for links. It often gives you 1.4.2.

Comment: Google search: "Java 7 XXX" with XXX = name of the class works 99% of the time. For example:[search for Java 7 Semaphore](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+7+semaphore).